# Specify container path for a group in the ldap filter

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I googled a lot about this problem, but haven't found anything.

I have a distinguishedName like this:

```
CN=MY_GROUP_NAME_PATTERN_*,OU=FourthLevel,OU=ThirdLevel,OU=SecondLevel,OU=FirstLevel,DC=mydomain,DC=net
```

I tried this as an LDAP-filter and it returns zero results. When I try this filter

```
CN=MY_GROUP_NAME_PATTERN_*
```

I get all my groups displayed. How can I specify the exact path for my groups, that only groups from this location are returned?

This group for example should not be caught by the filter.

```
CN=MY_GROUP_NAME_PATTERN_*, OU=FirstLevelNeighbor
```

In other words: How can I specify more than one filter property?

Comment: What LDAP client are you using? Look for a configuration option or parameter named something like "search base" or "base dn", and then pass the distinguished name of the OU to that option/parameter. Make sure the "scope" of the query is set to "subtree" or "recursive" or similar

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm using Get-ADGroup in powershell. But this is only meant to verify the filter, which shall be used in Atlassian Jira later. I can't use a search base parameter there, as there is only one field for the filter string. At least I'm not aware of any method.

Comment: But give me a minute. I think, I might have figured it out. There is a Base DN field further up.